# Opendaylight Rolling upgrade

Tags: apache-karaf, opendaylight, akka-cluster

We are using Nitrogen-SR3 release and using customized 2 node cluster. We have to support "Rolling Upgrade" (no downtime to cluster) of our entire application. Please let us know can we add/remove nodes dynamically from/to "Akka" cluster and form a new cluster (after upgrade of all nodes) programmatically. If yes, could you please give us the steps.

Thanks